# How to create a load balancer service on openshift with https (IBM CLOUD)

Tags: https, dns, openshift, ibm-cloud, load-balancing

I have an Openshift cluster (on IBMCLOUD) and in order to secure my DNS record,i follow up the next steps :

1- Secure openshift route https
2- Declare 443 port on Loadbalancer service
3- Declare my Loadbalancer as CNAME on my DNS record (-Azure- as extrenal DNS records)

But after all those steps my loadbalancer didn't listen to the https port.

so How to create a load balancer service on openshift with https

Comment: A `Route` is exposed on the shared LoadBalancer provisioned for your Ingress Controller. If you're OK with the LB being shared, just stop at this point. If you're exposing a LoadBalancer `Service`, then skip creating a `Route` since your `Service` bypasses that anyway. Finally, Load Balancers listen for _everything_, so it's up to your _application_ to listen on port 443 (or define a port mapping in your `Service`, `port` -> `targetPort`)

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, i would like to ask u about if i should add a ssl certicate or not in my route ?

Comment: It's up to you. The Ingress Controller _should_ have a default wildcard, in which case you can inherit that with an `edge` secure route and empty `tls` section. If you want to attach a cert to the route, then you can use the `tls` section in an `edge` route. Finally, you can use a `passthrough` route, and put the cert and key in directly in your pod